# iOS7 UITableViewCell Group

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image]

iOS7 and iOS6 UITableView's style(UITableViewStyleGrouped) is different;iOS7 I set cell.layer.borderWidth, middle row too thick.I want iOS7 and iOS6 UITableView's style(UITableViewStyleGrouped)is same.How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, iOS7 and iOS6 don't have the same design...

If you want the same design for both, you need to create a design which doesn't rely on the "iOS Design" itself.

If you just need to change the separator height, go here : [How to increase the UITableView seperator height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521310/how-to-increase-the-uitableview-seperator-height)

Answer (score 0):

Look & Feel are different in iOS 7 so, the user wants a different layout. If you set the same layout for iOS 6 and iOS 7 does not make sense because you give the impression that the app aren't optimized for iOS 7.