# ios tableView clearColor seperator

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have set my tableView's background color, and I want there is space(10px) around each cell show that color.

e.g.(ignore the red line)

[image]

What I am doing now is make the cell embed a smaller view, and set the cell's background to be clear. But it is annoying to create such embed view again and again.

So, I am seeking for a better solution, I believe it would be good if i can increase separator's height. But the old answers did not solve my problem.

([How to increase the UITableView separator height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521310/how-to-increase-the-uitableview-separator-height))

**EDIT:**

However, if I add my own separator in cell. I may not able to set the cell having round corner

Comment: One of the possible solutions is to use collectionView instead of tableView. It might sound like an overkill, but it is a great way to get maximum flexibility.

Comment: @almas I did not learned how to use collectionView yet. I will try that

Comment: What do you mean by "embed view again and again"?

Comment: @rmaddy I will create multiple tableViews like this one. So, in each tableView's cell, I have to embed a smaller view

Comment: That is what custom table cell classes are for. Write a custom cell class once and reuse it where needed.

Comment: @rmaddy I do the embed stuff in IB, so there is no way to create a class

Comment: You create a custom class, then in the IB cell's class inspector, you set it to use your custom class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought of just making the cell height taller and putting your own separator on the bottom of your custom cells? Nice table layout by the way.

Comment: there will be a problem when i make the cell to be round corner

Comment: Thats true.  What if you just made another custom table view cell that is a separator.  I know thats probably not your favorite solution, but a 10 pixel height tableview cell that you can put in every other cell would work for your needs.

Comment: You can set rounded corner on the embedded view, and not on the whole cell.

Comment: @almas has a good point, but he is trying to avoid having the embedded view

Comment: @almas that is what I am doing now.

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog That sounds interesting! I will do that!

Comment: Woo Hoo! I use that method a lot for custom section headers or spaces between sections of custom table view cells

Answer (score 2):

1. Set the `tableView`'s `separatorStyle` to `.None`.
2. Create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass.
3. In the storyboard (or xib if you created one for the custom cell), add a subview that's inset the amount that you want padded on all four sides.
4. If you want rounded views, do that on the custom cell's subview (e.g. `subview.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0`, `subview.layer.masksToBounds = true`).
5. Set the custom cell's ContentView to have a clear background.
6. Set the table view's background to that lovely shade of blue.
7. Set the cell subview's background color to white.

You don't have to use the cell repeatedly in InterfaceBuilder. Just give the cell an ID, and in your implementation of the table view's data source, dequeue a cell instance using that ID and set the values of the labels inside it.

Comment: thanks for your long answer! However, I do cell in different tableView has different content. So, I cannot reuse cells like this

Comment: All of the cells have the same basic content: a white background view, a blue circle on the left, a description label, a date label, and whatever that "9/12" on the right means. If each of those labels and views has an outlet to it, then when you dequeue a cell for each row, you can set the values of that cell's fields.

Comment: I mean, I will need to create cells that do not have images, some cells may only contains images in different tableViews. BTW, i believe it is not suitable to "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" in other tableView

Comment: You create a prototype cell for each style you'll display.

Comment: it seems "prototype cell" can only be used in one table view, app will crash if you try to create "prototype cell" defined in other tableView

Comment: Kind of. Your cell type has to be *registered* with each table it'll be used in. When you add prototype cells in a xib or storyboard, they get registered automatically. But if you want a cell class to be used in more than one table, you have a couple of choices: you can create a xib and refer to it in multiple tables, or you can call `registerNib: forCellReuseIdentifier:" in the code for both tables' data sources. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540345/how-do-you-load-custom-uitableviewcells-from-xib-files) is a good summary of how you can do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I prefer create cell to separate them though