# Shadow on a UITableViewCell disappears when scrolling

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView that has one cell with a shadow. When I do scrolling up and down, the shadow of the cell disappears. As I thought this was a reuse-issue I already only ever use this one cell with a shadow.What may be the problem here ?

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = UITableViewCell()

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 3: cell = shadowBasicCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        case 4: cell = contentCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        case 5: cell = contentCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        case 6: cell = contentCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        case 11: cell = contentCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        default: cell = basicCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        }

        return cell
    }



    func contentCellAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> ContentCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(contentCellIdentifier) as! ContentCell
        setTitleForCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
        setContentForCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    func shadowBasicCellAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> ShadowBasicCell {

      //  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(shadowBasicCellIdentifier) as! ShadowBasicCell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(shadowBasicCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ShadowBasicCell

       // let cell = ShadowBasicCell(style: <#T##UITableViewCellStyle#>, reuseIdentifier: <#T##String?#>)

        cell.icon.image = upperTableIcons[indexPath.row]
        cell.textlabel.text = upperTableLabels[indexPath.row]
        cell.textlabel.textColor = UIColor.dmvBody1()
        cell.textlabel.font = UIFont.dmvBody1()
        cell.valueLabel.font = UIFont.dmvBody1()
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None


        cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5, 5);
        cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2;
        cell.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0;
        cell.clipsToBounds = false

        let shadowFrame: CGRect = (cell.layer.bounds)
        let shadowPath: CGPathRef = UIBezierPath(rect: shadowFrame).CGPath
        cell.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: cell.frame.width, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        return cell

    }

    func basicCellAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> BasicCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(basicCellIdentifier) as! BasicCell
        cell.icon.image = upperTableIcons[indexPath.row]
        cell.textlabel.text = upperTableLabels[indexPath.row]
        cell.textlabel.textColor = UIColor.dmvBody1()
        cell.valueLabel.text = upperTableValues[indexPath.row]
        cell.valueLabel.textColor = UIColor.dmvBody1()
        cell.textlabel.font = UIFont.dmvBody1()
        cell.valueLabel.font = UIFont.dmvBody1()
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        if indexPath.row > 6 {cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.dmvBeige30()} else {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }
       return cell
    }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine at a first glance (though your `switch` statement with its identical `case` repetition is very silly). But here's a bit of advice: do not have the cell cast a shadow with its layer and `clipsToBounds` turned off. Instead, _draw_ the shadow _in_ the cell in such a way that it _looks_ like the cell is casting a shadow. The way you're doing it, scrolling will stutter, because you're making the rendering system work its butt off.

Comment: ok. How do I draw a shadow?

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem myself: The reason the shadow wasn't seen, was because it was covered by the cell beneath that got redrawn. I set the background color of the following cell to clearColor() and everything is fine now.

Comment: That's a really nice way around, thanks for that. But have you managed to overcome with a better solution?