# How to create space between 2 table view cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

I have a `TableViewCell` which have the border at the surrounding.So what some space at the bottom of each cell.

**Here is what I want :**

[image]

I see a lot of question is work for cell which doesnt have any border.What I want is the space is outside the border at the bottom of every cell.

**Now my cell is look like this**

[image]

So how can I achieve the output that I stated in first picture?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase the UITableView separator height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521310/how-to-increase-the-uitableview-separator-height)

Comment: @MoAbdul-Hameed I want the separator outside the prototype cell ya..cause I have a border surrounding the cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easily accomplished with static/dynamic tableView cells & don't give the border to the cell itself but to the subview named TopView

```
 tableViewCell
    ->ContentView
     ->TopView ---- with border height(static/dynamic)
     ->DownView transparent ---- height(10)
```

with

```
 tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

Comment: so the `top` is a uiview?

Comment: Hey bro,I cant create a 2 view inside the `contentView`.once I make it,the contranist all move,you see what question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48140066/why-all-the-element-moved-when-adding-a-constraint-in-storyboard. do you have any other solution??

Comment: send me demo for each and i will fix it for you

Comment: how can I send u ya??

Comment: push demos to github or upload it to any site say Dropbox or mediaFire