# Why all the element moved when adding a constraint in storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard, swift4

I design all my element nicely for a prototype cell of `tableView`,but whenever I add a new constraint for my element,all element just moved and become like image below:

[image]

It happen often,may I know why is this happen and how to prevent it?

**EDIT :**

For example,before adding constraint it look like this

[image]

The white part in the center is a stack view,so I set it to `leading = 0` and `trailing=0`.And then I add a constraint inside the `stack view` to `leading=0` which it align with the `stackview` all element moved again and become like this:

[image]

As you can see,all thing just disappear.Why is this happen ya??

The constrainst that I adding is like below:

> Status Label.leading = leading

It happen also when I set the spacing of the `stackview` to 10,all the element also gone.

**Edit:**

I have a red arrow appear in storyboard,I suggest the `Content Priority Ambiguous`,but I after change the priority as to 252 as suggested,all element just disappear again.

Comment: Can you add screenshots before adding the constraint and also that constraint , it may that constraint doesn't fit properly with existing ones

Comment: @Sh_Khan wait sir,cause I delete all the constraints and do it again ady..wait a minute

Comment: @Sh_Khan Hey sir,I updated the question,please take a look..tq

Comment: Where in layout is the Status  label ????

Comment: is inside the stack view,when I change the constraint of the label,the element moved..

Comment: If you see the red arrow click it and  post conflicts

Comment: ya.I see the red arrow,and change the content priority as suggested,once I change,it disappear again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the bottom constraint of the bottom most element attached to the content view and add all your remaining constraints & with stackView spacing , then re add the bottom constraint again

Comment: hey sir,I already remove the bottom constraint and add top,leading and trailing constraint only.But when I move anything inside the stackView..All constraint for all element just changed and move..

Comment: ya still not solved..Later may be I try again..do this have any possible problem??