# How to create UITableView separator look good?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

The basic separators look very simple and one dimension, but most of the table views out there have a good looking separators, I thing it looks good because it has shadow or something that makes it look 3D. How do they to that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374990/how-to-customize-tableview-seperator-in-iphone
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227420/iphone-uitableview-place-an-image-for-separator
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804632/uitableview-separator-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could create your table either programmatically/XIB.
Now either in Your code or XIB set:

```
yourTable.separatorStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

now in tableview delegate method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:businessLogicIdentifier]
                autorelease];


        customSeperator=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (cell.frame.origin.y), 320, 1)];
        customSeperator.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:customSeperator];  
}
```

now at line (customSeperator.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];) you could also try

```
[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"]];
```

for using Your Own Image.
Hope it help you

Comment: thanks, eventually I created a background image for my cell that includes the separator, I think that is the best solution for me :)